# How can i Implement SlideShow in android?

Tags: android

I wish to develop an Slide Show application in android. My requirement is, i had a set of 20 (not a constant) images in my drawable folder (not a External Storage). **Now i show this set of images with in a certain constat time limit**. I had a code for slideshow for android basic sample in that code **how can i set time interval**. My code is,

```
SlideShow.java:


   package com.fsp.slideview;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Gallery;
import android.widget.Gallery.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.ImageSwitcher;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ViewSwitcher;

public class SlideShow extends Activity implements
        AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener, ViewSwitcher.ViewFactory {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        setContentView(R.layout.slide_show);

        mSwitcher = (ImageSwitcher) findViewById(R.id.switcher);
        mSwitcher.setFactory(this);
        mSwitcher.setInAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
                android.R.anim.fade_in));
        mSwitcher.setOutAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
                android.R.anim.fade_out));

        Gallery g = (Gallery) findViewById(R.id.gallery);
        g.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
        g.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    }

    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView parent, View v, int position, long id) {
        mSwitcher.setImageResource(mImageIds[position]);
    }

    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView parent) {
    }

    public View makeView() {
        ImageView i = new ImageView(this);
        i.setBackgroundColor(0xFF000000);
        i.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
        i.setLayoutParams(new ImageSwitcher.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
        return i;
    }

    private ImageSwitcher mSwitcher;

    public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
            mContext = c;
        }

        public int getCount() {
            return mThumbIds.length;
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ImageView i = new ImageView(mContext);

            i.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
            i.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
            i.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            i.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.picture_frame);
            return i;
        }

        private Context mContext;

    }

    private Integer[] mThumbIds = { R.drawable.img1, R.drawable.img2,
            R.drawable.img2, R.drawable.img3, R.drawable.img4, R.drawable.img5,
            R.drawable.img6, R.drawable.img7 };

    private Integer[] mImageIds = { R.drawable.img1, R.drawable.img1,
            R.drawable.img2, R.drawable.img3, R.drawable.img4, R.drawable.img5,
            R.drawable.img6, R.drawable.img7 };

}
```

and the xml file is, slide_show.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <ImageSwitcher
        android:id="@+id/switcher"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

    <Gallery
        android:id="@+id/gallery"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="#55000000"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:spacing="16dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: hi my friend , i used your code in this post also added the answerd code snippet to your code , but when run app it gave me just normal gallery with image slider strip in button of screen not ( image slide show) which im try to get , would you please help me , thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    final Handler mHandler = new Handler();


    int delay = 1000; // delay for 1 sec.

    int period = 8000; // repeat every 4 sec.

    Timer timer = new Timer();

    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

    public void run() {

         mHandler.post(mUpdateResults);

    }

    }, delay, period);

}
```

Comment: please put this code also   final Handler mHandler = new Hander();

Comment: What is this mUpdateResults instance? Where do you have that from?